# Creating a dummy variable for properties that intersect the buffer I created

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, buffer, expression

I created a 1000 foot buffer around waterways for a single county in the U.S. I need to create a dummy variable for the properties that intersect the buffer I created. It would be 1 if the property intersects and 0 if not. I need to add this dummy variable to the parcel shapefile attribute table.

Comment: You could be overthinking it.  What I would do is create a new selection from the Parcels layer using the buffer layer: "Vector | Research Tools | Select by Location".  Then open the parcels attribute table and use the field calculator to add a new field with the expression "1" and tick the "Only update selected features" box.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **refFunctions**  plugin. Install it and use the following expression in Field Calculator for parcel layer:

```
if ( intersecting_geom_count('buffer_layer_name') > 0, 1, 0 )
```

Comment: Since QGIS 3.16, the function of the refFuntions plugin are available natively in QGIS expressions, see https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog316/index.html#port-reffunctions-to-core